# How to best convert a std::string_view to q QString?

Tags: qt, c++17

I have a library that gives me a `string_view`. What's the best way to get it into a `QString` (not a `QStringView`)?

I made `QString::fromStdString(std::string(key).c_str())`, but is that the best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `c_str()`, you don't need it, since `fromStdString()` takes a `std::string` (hence the name):

```
QString::fromStdString(std::string(key))
```

You can also drop the explicit string construction, since `std::string` can be constructed from a `std::string_view`:

```
QString::fromStdString(key)
```

That being said, if the `std::string_view` is null-terminated (which is not guaranteed), you can use the `QString` constructor that accepts a `char*`:

```
QString(key.data())
```

Or, if the `std::string_view` is encoded in Latin-1, you can use:

```
QString::fromLatin1(key.data(), key.size())
```

Or, if encoded in UTF-8:

```
QString::fromUtf8(key.data(), key.size())
```

Or, if encoded in the user's default locale:

```
QString::fromLocal8Bit(key.data(), key.size())
```

Comment: Going through `std::string` involves an extraneous copy, while its useful result is equivalent to the `fromUtf8` way.

Comment: `QString(key.data())` is problematic since `string_view::data` does not have to be null-terminated: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data#Notes

Comment: @MattEding maybe you missed the part where my answer said: "***IF** the `std::string_view` is null-terminated (which is **NOT** guaranteed), ...*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I must have been sleepier than I had realized when I had made my comment. Sorry about that.